# What is the statistical equilibrium for this simulation of happy bubbles?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables, random, simulation

## Happy Bubbles

I hope this is not too specific or practical, but I just made a simulation of sorts and seem to have hit quite close to an equilibrium (by accident). Now I am wondering if and how you would calculate the exact function or exact value for this situations statistical "sweetspot".

### The Problem

I was playing around with D3.js and created a canvas with randomly appearing bubbles with a 5% chance every iteration. Also every iteration bubbles touching any border will disappear. This can happen because the bubbles move around every iteration.

### The Parameters

- Starting with a single bubble
- Every bubble has a x- and a y-coordinate which represents the center of the bubble
- Bubble Size: 20px radius
- Iterationlength: 100 ms
- Canvas Size: 600px by 600px
- Bubble Speed: -5px to 5px on X-Axis and Y-Axis

  - ([Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) * 10) - 5 (the random number is a floating point number between 0 (including) and 1 (excluding))
- Starting position per bubble: Math.random() * 600 for x and y coordinate (seperately)
- Bubble pops when it gets within 20px of any outer edge (again using the center as reference)

### The Equilibrium

With these Parameters new bubbles and disappearing bubbles seem to cancel each other out. The number of bubbles ranges from 100 to 130 but has not breached those limits in more then an hour.

### The Question

Do these Parameters ensure such an equilibirum or is it nothing special, that the number seems to be rather stable? How would one calculate this?

### Caveats

One I can think of is that the bubble could move from 20.000001 to 15.000001 in one iteration. But I guess that is a small detail. Maybe this isn't even relevant.

### Edit:

**[Here is the jsFiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/t1xhtu5e/)** (Be carefull with less then 100 ms iteration time, it might stress the browser)

Comment: I don't think I understand you model completely. Based on my understanding of your model, the estimated lifetime for a bubble should be around

$$\frac{560}{5}{\bf E}\left[\min\left(\frac{p_x}{v_x},\frac{p_y}{v_y}\right)\right]
= \frac{560}{5}\frac{5}{6} = \frac{560}{6} \approx 93.3333
$$
where $p_x,p_y,v_x,v_y$ are 4 random variables uniformly sampled from $[0,1]$. It is close but I don't think it should not be off from your number for more than $10$% like here.

Comment: What do you mean the bubble pops when it is within $20$px of the outer edge. Does it pop immediately or have some probability of survive? Another thing is whether the velocity is independent. Does velocity like ($5$px,$5$px) allowed? Can't think of other factors that explain this amount of discrepancy.

Comment: Bubbles pop immediately when their center coordinate comes within 20px of the canvas edges, in every iteration. The traveled distance is described above: (Math.random() * 10) - 5 in px

Comment: In that case, I can't explain the last 10-20% diff from your number. Things like the move is discrete steps should only make a few % correction. BTW, do the intermediate position and velocities are stored in screen coordinates (i.e in integers) or in floating points all the times?

Comment: It's all stored in floating point numbers, though I am not sure what you mean with "intermediate position and velocities". Every iteration the x and y coordinate are overwritten with the old value plus the deviation mentioned above. And all that is still floating point. And I am not sure how your formula works, so I can't comment about that. If you want post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple model to estimate $\mathcal{N}$, the expected number of bubbles after some sort of equilibrium is reached. In this model, the bubble will be randomly displaced at each iteration.

The first claim is $\mathcal{N}$ is proportional to $\mathcal{T}$, the expected life time of a bubble . After we start the system and wait long enough for the system to stabilize, there are two ways to estimate $\mathcal{N}$.

1. Observe the system for $N \gg 1 $ iterations. Sum the number of bubbles observed in these iterations and then divide the final result by $N$.
2. Follow all bubbles created and destroyed during these $N$ iterations. Sum over their life time and then divide by $N$.

In general, these two ways of counting will differ by a number which is of the order of $\mathcal{T}$. If $\mathcal{T}$ is finite.
This two method will produce the same estimation of $\mathcal{N}$ as $N \to \infty$.

If on average, $\alpha$ bubble is created during each iteration, one will have

$$\mathcal{N} = \alpha \mathcal{T}$$

In this problem $\alpha = 0.05$. If the bubble is created within $20$px from the edge, the bubble will be destroyed in the next iteration. 
The same thing happens to the bubble at the end of its life. All this process
will add $1$ to the expected life time $\mathcal{T}$.

For a probability $\left(\frac{560}{600}\right)^2$, the bubble will be created
within the safe zone $[20,580] \times [20,580]$.
Let $L = 580-20 = 560$ and $t$ be the number of iteration since the bubble 
is created. Introduce random variables $X, Y, \eta_x(t), \eta_y(t)$ and we will
update the position of the bubble by following recipe

$$\begin{cases}
x(0) &= 20+X\\
y(0) &= 20+Y
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\begin{cases}
x(t) &= x(t-1) + \eta_x(t)\\
y(t) &= y(t-1) + \eta_y(t)\\
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ for }\quad t > 0
\tag{*1}
$$

Subject to the constraint the bubble is created in the safe-zone, the variables $X, Y$ and $\eta_x(t), \eta_y(t)$ are uniform random variables taking values over $[0,L]$ and $[-5,5]$ respectively.

Let $T$ be the random variable corresponds to the life time of a bubble (excluding the last iteration discussed above).
Introduce a function
$$u(x,y) = {\bf E}\big[ T \big| (X,Y) = (x,y) \big]\quad\text{ for }\quad (x,y) \in [0,L]\times[0,L]$$
If $u(x,y)$ can be approximated by a continuous function, then the 
$\mathcal{T}$ we want will be given by a integral

$$\mathcal{T} = 1 + \left(\frac{560}{600}\right)^2 {\bf E}[T]
\quad\text{ with }\quad
{\bf E}[T] = 
\frac{1}{L^2} \int_0^L\int_0^L u(x,y) dx dy
$$

We can view the random update in $(*1)$ as a Brownian motion. If equilibrium has been reached, we should have

$$u(x,y) = {\bf E}\big[ u(x + \eta_x, y + \eta_y) \big] + 1$$
This implies $u(x,y)$ should approximately satisfies a PDE

$$u(x,y) = u(x,y) 
+  \frac{{\bf E}[\eta_x^2]}{2} \frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial x^2}
+  \frac{{\bf E}[\eta_y^2]}{2} \frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial y^2}
+ 1
$$
Let $\sigma^2 = {\bf E}[\eta_x^2] = \frac{5^2}{3}$, this has the form of a Possion
equation
$$\nabla^2 u(x,y) = -\frac{2}{\sigma^2}$$
and the appropriate condition for this problem is $u(x,y) = 0$ on the boundaries.

If I'm not mistaken, the solution of these boundary value problem is given by

$$u(x,y) = \frac{32L^2}{\sigma^2\pi^4} \sum_{n=1,\text{odd}}^\infty\sum_{m=1,\text{odd}}^{\infty} 
\frac{1}{n m (n^2+m^2)} 
\sin\left(\frac{\pi n x}{L}\right)
\sin\left(\frac{\pi m y}{L}\right)
$$
Integrate this, we get

$$\mathcal{T} = 1 + \left(\frac{560}{600}\right)^2\frac{128L^2}{\sigma^2\pi^6} K
\quad\text{ where }\quad
K = \sum_{n=1,\text{odd}}^\infty\sum_{m=1,\text{odd}}^{\infty} 
\frac{1}{n^2 m^2 (n^2+m^2)} 
\approx 0.52973
$$
Substitute this into the formula $\mathcal{N} = \alpha T$, we get $$\mathcal{N}_{600} \approx 115.65$$
which now falls within the observed range of OP's numerical result. 
If one repeat the same argument to other canvas size $s$, we have

$$\mathcal{N}_s = 1 + \left(1 - \frac{40}{s}\right)^2
\frac{384(s - 40)^2}{25\pi^6} K
$$
Following is a table for $\mathcal{N}_s$ for other canvas sizes $s$:

$$
\begin{array}{r:r}
s & \mathcal{N}_s\\
\hline
300 &  21.54\\
400 &  44.47\\
500 &  75.84\\
600 & 115.65\\
700 & 163.92\\
800 & 220.64\\
900 & 285.82
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I will need some time to really get all this and see if I can spot the missing link to my model. Meanwhile, maybe for testing the formula: Changing the canvas size to 900 * 900 yields an equilibrium between 260 and 300. I also lowered the iteration time to 10ms.

Comment: @tre the formula is now off a lot, it give $131.87$ so the discrepancy increases a lot. I will suggest you do two experiments, repeat the simulation for several canvas size while keeping everything else fixed and repeat the simulation for several iteration time while keeping everything else fixed. In both cases, try to find how the number of bubbles depends on the changing variable. In my model, it should only depends on the canvas size linearly and doesn't depend on the iteration time.

Comment: I will. I think a shorter iteration time should not change anything, except that the equilibrium is reached quicker (which I would confirm with looking at it)

Comment: I added a version to try out in the question.

Comment: I see what is missing in this model now. I wrongly assume once the bubble is created, the bubble keep its velocity. Instead, you update the bubble's velocity in every iteration. So the correct dependence of canvas side should be quadratic rather than linear.

Comment: ALright, the velocity was something I could not really find in your appraoch, now I know why :) Could you update the fomula? I marked your answer as the right one.

Comment: @tre I updated the model, I now get $115$ for canvas size $600$ and $285$ for canvas size $900$. It now seems approximately correct. BTW, the approximation I used here should work better for larger $N$.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sense that there is some kind of equilibrium. I've been performing some calculations but have not gotten far. Perhaps it is would be interesting to start with a number of bubbles higher than, say, 500, and see whether the number of bubbles converges back to the said range.

**Edit:** I wrote a script based on your description of the system and obtained very similar results (i.e. the number of bubbles hovered around $120$). However, I wrote another script to simulate the average number of iterations it took for a bubble to reach one of the borders. This number is somewhere around $2500$. In other words, the average bubble has about $\frac{1}{2500}$ chance of reaching a border in the next iteration. In equilibrium,
$$n\cdot \frac{1}{\ell_{\mathrm{path}}} = p_{\mathrm{new}},$$ 
where $n$ is the number of bubbles currently existing, $\ell_{\mathrm{path}}$ is the average path length, and $p_{\mathrm{new}}$ is the probability that a new bubble appears in any given iteration. And as it turns out, $$120 \cdot \frac{1}{2500} = 0.048 \approx 0.05 = p_{\mathrm{new}}.$$
This is, however, not an analytic approach yet.

Comment: Interesting idea, I will try that.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work. Starting with 500 Bubbles we reach 200 within minutes and are now at 106 after about 20 more minutes

Comment: Can you simulate this with 900px canvas size?

Comment: I simulated 5000 bubbles on a 900x900 canvas and got an average path length of 6328 iterations.

Comment: Which get's us 0.047 with an equilibrium of 300 bubbles. Somehow this fits, while the calculations in the other answer are off.

Comment: Obviously this fits, since it must hold in equilibrium. The really interesting question is how we can express $n$ (the average number of bubbles in equilibrium) as a function of canvas size.

Answer (score 0):

There will always be an equilibrium.  You have a fixed rate of bubble productions, but the popping rate will be proportional to how many bubbles are on screen at the time.  Thus the number of bubbles will rise until the popping rate matches.

Answer (score -1):

I fitted the average path lengths I obtained.

$x$ axis: Size of square canvas $\times 100$ pixels.

$y$ axis: Average number of iterations per bubble.

[image: My Image]